# Cannot resize ubuntu partition with gparted

Tags: gparted, resize

I don't know why but I'm unable to resize my Ubuntu partition. I've tried from both Windows and Ubuntu but even when I have unallocated space and have disabled swap and booting from a USB i can't get it to work

[image: Gparted window]

[image: Resizing /dev/sda4]

I've tried following other posts but none work, I'm not sure what I'm exactly doing wrong. I get it's because they aren't contiguous but when moving my swap partition under the unallocated, I'm told I'll have trouble booting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot resize because there is no free space before */dev/sda4*. */dev/sda3* is just before */dev/sda4*. In your current setup you can extend the */dev/sda5* or */dev/sda3* only (assuming the partition type is *Primary*).

Delete the swap partition and create a new one from unallocated space, the you will have free space before */dev/sda4/* . If you have an active linux installation (that is using the swap),then use a live usb to edit it's */etc/fstab* file and change uuid for old swap partition with new one. You won't have any booting issues.

Comment: Much better to move the existing swap partition to avoid trouble with changed UUID.

Comment: Thanks I just moved the swap partition let's hope it works